# How to define temporary table values in a subquery in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am approaching this issue from a non DBA perspective, as in I do not have permissions to create new tables for the database. I am trying to work around this by using a subquery in Oracle kind of like this sudo code:

```
With temptable as ('col1name', 'col2name', 1,'a',2,'b')
Select * from temptable where col1name = 1
```

With the temptable looking like

```
Col1name | Col2name
1           a
2           b
```

And the output being row 1. I know it is not the easiest way to do it, but it is all I can think of to accomplish my task until I can get the admin to approve a new table. I have searched a lot but I can't find an answer. Is there a simple way to define temporary table data like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to a CTE (common table expresssion) as suggested by Gordon, you can also use a query as an old-school inline view.

For example:

```
 SELECT tt.col1name
      , tt.col2name
   FROM ( SELECT 1 AS col1name, 'a' AS col2name FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'b' FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'c' FROM DUAL
        ) tt
  WHERE tt.col1name = 1
  ORDER
     BY tt.col1name
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just do this as:

```
with temptable as (
      select 1 as col1name, 'a' col2name from dual union all
      select 2, 'b' from dual
     )
Select *
from temptable
where col1name = 1;
```